# How to prevent field validating as empty after submit

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm developing a chat like component that makes an ajax call on submit.
There is a single field with class="required" to be validate by jquery validate.

Problem is that right after the submit as there is no page refresh, jQuery validate adds the error class, is there any way to prevent this?

Thank you very much for any help.

Regards

HTML

```
<form id="test_form">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#test_form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    if ($(form).valid()) {
        //Ajax call here in the real project.
        result = $(form).serialize();
        //If ajax is successfull
            $('#results').append(result+"<br>");
        //Reset fields
        $(form)[0].reset();
    }
  });
});
```

I provide a jsfiddle to see the issue yourself.
http://jsfiddle.net/jCQEw/2/

Comment: Can someone explain to me why I got downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the required class on your input, it is useless because validator is then configured with a rule which states that the "test" field is required and its value has to be 5 characters long to be accepted ...

Then here is the correct syntax.. [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jCQEw/3/)

```
$(function () {    
    $("#test_form").validate({
        rules: {
            test: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }, messages: {
            test: {
                required: "This field is required !!",
                minlength: "{0} characters needed !!"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var $form = $(form);
            alert('called');
            //Ajax call here in the real project.
            result = $form.serialize();
            //If ajax is successfull
            $('#results').append(result+"<br>");
            //Reset fields
            $form[0].reset();
            return false;
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way if I don't want to use the submithandler of jquery validate? I would prefer, in order to keep the code as clean as possible to bind my own submit event.

Comment: The submitHandler is actually yours ! It means you can just prevent the default behaviour by returning false at the end ... Then you are free to do what ever you want inside of it, like ajax call to manually post input values. When this handler get executed, you can be sure that fields have been validated regarding rules you set ... This piece of code is clean because it is using the validator plugin API  as it is meant to be used .. Does this make sense to you ?

Comment: Sure it makes sense, it's just to keep integrity across the project, for cleanliness I only use classes and simply form.validate(), but I see your point, I might be changing my ways.

Comment: if the handler might be used with another form elsewhere you can obviously declare it as a global function then pass its reference as the value of the submitHandler validator parameter